# The quotient embedding of tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here is a quotation of a book:

> Let $A, B$ be two $C^*$-algebras and $J\subset A$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra, then there is a dense embedding
>   $$\frac{A\odot B}{J\odot B}\hookrightarrow\frac{A\otimes_{\max} B}{J\otimes_{\max} B}$$

Here, the $\odot$ denote the algebraic tensor product. However, what is this embedding? I mean for the element $x+J\odot B$ in $\frac{A\odot B}{J\odot B}$, what is the image of it in $\frac{A\otimes_{\max} B}{J\otimes_{\max} B}$? Or how to construct this embeding?

Comment: What book? What does the notation mean?

Comment: Judging by other recent questions, this is likely from the proof of Prop 3.7.1 in Brown and Ozawa's $C^*$-algebras and Finite Dimensional Approximations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You map the product to the product. Barring any commentary otherwise, it's almost unthinkable that they could mean anything other than a homomorphism generated by the correspondence

$$ x \odot y \mapsto x \otimes_{\max} y $$

Comment: The issue is showing that your map is injective. A priori it could be possible that $J\otimes_\max B$ contains elements of $(A\odot B)\setminus (J\odot B)$. The key to the argument is to show that it is not the case.

Comment: @Martin: It also needs to be shown (although this part is easy) that it's well-defined too. But given the content of the opening post, I think the poster really is stuck on just what the map should be, rather than how to prove it has the desired properties.

Comment: @Hurkyl But what is $x\odot y$? Is it the  elementary tensor product? And what is $x\otimes_{max} y$?

Comment: @Belle: Yes: usually if we use a symbol $\square$ to express a tensor product $A \square B$, we also use the same symbol for the corresponding bilinear operation $A \times B \to A \square B$.

Comment: @Hurkyl But what does your $x\otimes_{max} y$ denote?

Comment: ... the image of $(x,y)$ under the bilinear map $A \times B \to A \otimes_{\max} B$.